# Raster files into DB2

Tags: db2, spatial

Team,

We have been loading shapefiles into DB2 using db2se import utilities.

I have been trying to find help to load Raster files and i wasnt able to find any help on this. it would be really helpful if I can get a guide on loading raster files into DB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you enable DB2 as an Enterprise GEoDB, it should work. 
The steps to enable using Arcgis desktop tool

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0029000000sn000000